# SSIS how to add lookup key to inserted rows

Tags: ssis

I have a problem where I need to have the dimension key for all rows in the data stream.

1. I use a lookup component to find the dimension key of the records
2. Records with no dimension key (lookup no match output) are redirect to a different output because they need to be inserted.
3. the no match output is multicated
4. the new records are inserted into the dimension.
5. a second lookup component should be executed after the records are inserted

   number 5 fails because I don't know how to wait for the ADO NET Destination to finish...

Is there any way to solve this other than dump the stream into raw files and use other data flow to resume the task?

[image]

Comment: The phrase "late arriving dimension" will be relevant to your question. I haven't found a satisfactory answer to the problem myself

Comment: you probably need to create a new DFT for step 5.

Comment: Why does the second lookup have to occur "after the records are inserted"? Is it because you are relying on an Identity to be generated in the target table or is it because you are actually looking up against the target table? Why can't you just put the lookup before the ADO NET Destaintion? For further discussion it may help to number the steps in your screenshot so we can refer to them. After many years of SSIS being around, IMHO it is still inferior to an ELT method (work done in the database not in the package)

Comment: @billinkc is not exactly an "late arriving" dimension because the dimensional data is arriving at the same time as a the fact ;)

Comment: @ElectricLlama yes, I trust the SQL server identity to generate the dimension keys.  And because i am using the Dimensional Modeling, i need the dimension key, therefore the lookup is repeated for the inserted rows.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you need the dimension key. Why do you need it in your lookup?

Comment: @ElectricLlama the lookup appends the dimensional key to the row (and latter will be used to insert the fact).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're doing now. Normally you would load the dimension fully first in its own data flow, then after this is fully complete, you load the fact, using the already populated dimension. You appear to be trying to load the fact and dimension in one data flow.

The only reason you'd do this in one data flow is if you couldn't seperate your distinct dimensions from your facts and your fact source is so huge you don't want to go through it twice. Normally you can preload a dimension without a large fact source but this is not always the case. It depends on your source data.

You could use a SEQUENCE (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) to do this in one data flow. This is a way of autogenerating a number without needing to insert it into a table, but your dimension would need to rely on a sequence *instead* of an identity. But you'd need to call it in some kind of inline script component or you might be able to trick a lookup component. It would be very slow.

Instead you should try building all of your dimensions in a prior load so that when you arrive at the fact load, all dimensions are already there.

In short the question is: Do you really need to do this in one big step? Can you prebuild your dimension in a prior data flow?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Kejser wrote a blogpost with a nice solution to this early arriving fact / late arriving dimension problem.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2009/05/13/assigning-surrogate-keys-to-early-arriving-facts-using-integration-services.aspx

Basically you use a second lookup with a partial cache. Whenever the partial lookup cache receives a non-matched row it will call a SQL statement and fetch data to populate the lookup cache. If you use a stored proc in this SQL statement you can first add it to dimension table and then use the SELECT statement to alter the cache.